# Load google maps v3 dynamically with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i try to load google maps v3 with ajax the result is:

```
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/2/8a/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the source code, i suppose that writes with javascript document.write();

how i can do this without iframe?

thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not supported. Please load the API using supported methods:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: what if you don't need it in a SPA later? Why should the user have to wait for the script to load?

Answer (score 32):

Found a practical way.

Fiddle here with custom event (jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/fZqqW/94/

```
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}

$(document).ready((function(){
    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3239, 5.0428),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
    function loadGoogleMaps(){
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    }
    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
    loadGoogleMaps();
})());​
```

**EDIT**
The `loadGoogleMaps` function might be more practical if declared in the global scope, especially when working in an ajax application. And a boolean check will prevent loading the api multiple times because of navigation.

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}
window.loadGoogleMaps = function(){
    if(gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3239, 5.0428),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
    window.loadGoogleMaps();
});
```

Comment: Worked for me out of box practically.

Comment: That's what I found too thanks for sharing. I updated my answer by the way, feel free to comment.

Comment: Worked for me too in a Durandal project.

Answer (score 16):

I've done it like so... this example uses jQuery and google map v3.x

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&region=nz&async=2&callback=MapApiLoaded", function () {});

function MapApiLoaded() {
   //.... put your map setup code here: new google.maps.Map(...) etc
}
```

Comment: it works ok but i get Warning in the js console:
`Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

Answer (score 8):

You must use this parameter 'callback=initialize' in the google maps API script to load with ajax:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Here is a google maps documentation:

[Cómo cargar el API de forma asíncrona](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=es&csw=1#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Comment: how do you insure this load later, I want my screen rendering script to run 1st.

Answer (score 5):

Simple and working solution (using jQuery):

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;

function loadGoogleMaps() { if(!gMapsLoaded) { $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&async=2&callback=GoogleMapsLoaded", function(){}); } else { GoogleMapsLoaded(); } }

function GoogleMapsLoaded() {

   gMapsLoaded = true;

   // your code here - init map ...
}
```

paste this in your scripts and then call function **loadGoogleMaps();** when you need it!

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a little bit Myster sample, that looks working well for me

```
    window.mapapiloaded = function () {
        console.log('$.ajax done: use google.maps');
        createusinggmaps();
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/-maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=true&region=it&async=2&callback=mapapiloaded',
        dataType: 'script',
        timeout: 30000, 
        success: function () {
            console.log('$.ajax progress: waiting for mapapiloaded callback');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('$.ajax fail: use osm instead of google.maps');
            createusingosm();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$LAB
  .setOptions({AlwaysPreserveOrder:true})
  .script("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&async=2")
  .script("http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/6/main.js")
  .script("script.js");
```

Inside of script.js initialize your map without googles load method for example:

```
Namespace.map = (function(){

    var map,
        markers = [];

    return{
        init: function(){
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),

                    mapOptions = {
                      zoom: 4,
                      center: myLatlng,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });

                markers.push(marker);
            }
    };

}());
```

Inside of script.js:

```
Namespace.map.init();

// Don't use: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Note: Do not rely on this method as Google changes the name of the second js file. Here is an example from their documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible. See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview?csw=1#js_api_loader_package)
On that page there is also a variant for manual loading, without library.

```
npm install @googlemaps/js-api-loader


import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"


const loader = new Loader({
apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
version: "weekly",
...additionalOptions,
});

loader.load().then(() => {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
 center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
 zoom: 8,
  });
});
```