# Google Maps API - undefined ROADMAP property?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm implementing two different kinds of google maps in my site.

1. The first simply shows pre-defined locations with markers using a MapTypeID of:

   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
2. The second allows the user to interact by dragging/dropping markers on the map etc.

I'm calling my API like so:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2.x&sensor=false&key=ABQIAAAAfK8z5AsiUZwKZF5CkZMF6BTAb5FWVJrlydeWm3IWDEdBI1HaUhTpyn3_qR2q3IPbPnQKou9lkKVqIA" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When launching my first map I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROADMAP' of undefined
```

If I load the Google Maps API an alternative way like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

The error from the first map goes away but I now get this error when launching my second map:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GOverlay is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: GControl is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: GControl is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: GCopyright is not defined
```

I think the issue has to do with one maps requiring an older version of the google maps API. Is it possible to load two seperate google maps API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` is a Google Maps v3 thing but everything else you have going on is a v2 thing.  Try `google.maps.MapType.G_NORMAL_MAP` instead.  (Then, think about upgrading the whole thing to v3.)

Comment: Thanks...I didn't realize I was using two different API versions.

Comment: To see the sample code with V3. Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3939845/644011

Answer (score 2):

If your using Google Maps v3

The javascript include for the google maps api has changed:

Instead of:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

there must be:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

please refer this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using this:

mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

use this:

mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

Comment: I don't think this is correct, because the `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` is valid and documented constant of Google Maps JavaScript API v3. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=es#MapTypeId. The initial issue in this question was that the author mixed the v2 (currently deprecated and dead) and v3 code.