# Load Google places asynchronously

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Since I'm going to use google maps and places in a mobile app, I don't want anything to slow down the app loading.

I've seen that on an edge network, my app is really slow starting. All my js are local so only google maps & places take a long time to load (loading is quick if I remove maps & places from the html file).

```
index.html
<script>....</script>
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&amp;sensor=false'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
</body>
```

I've found on [Load google maps v3 dynamically with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922764/load-google-maps-v3-dynamically-with-ajax) how to download Google Maps asynchronously :

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false&async=2&callback=MapApiLoaded", function () {});

function MapApiLoaded() {
   $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
   $.getScript("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false");
   $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
   alert('loading places done');
}
```

I receive the alert and I've checked that $.getScript() returns successfully but when I try to use places I get the following error in the javascript console : google maps places is undefined.

I've tried to only have places in the html file and load asynchronously Google Maps but it doesn't work either.

Any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're loading the Maps API twice. Just do it once, with the places library included:

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=MapApiLoaded");

function MapApiLoaded() {
    alert('loading Maps API and Places library done');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I've got another question. MapApiLoaded is called when Google Maps has been loaded and it's working. Would you know if there is an event triggered when the Places library is also loaded ?

Comment: I've added a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135608/how-to-know-when-google-places-has-loaded-and-is-ready-asynchronously

Comment: Hmm... I was under the impression that all libraries would be loaded before the callback is called. If I do a `console.log( google.maps.places );` at the beginning of `MapApiLoaded` it shows the object is present. But I guess maybe only a stub of the library has been loaded at that point and not the full library perhaps?

Comment: Also I meant to ask about the `async=2` in your Maps API URL. I haven't seen that parameter in the V3 Maps API; do you have a reference for that? I have seen it [used with the V2 API](https://www.google.com/search?q=maps+api+async=2).

Comment: I copied the async=2 from someone's code. I removed it and it hasn't changed anything - I also found out that it was undocumented. I found a solution for my problem and have posted it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135608/how-to-know-when-google-places-has-loaded-and-is-ready-asynchronously/17135990#17135990

Comment: this just saved my life :)