# Load Script and Execute only if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to find if there are any divs with class="map" in a page [Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/jBrfd).

If there are, and only in that case, load Google Maps API.

Then use it to load the maps into the divs using data attributes for lat and long values.

So I have the following:

```
<div class="map" data-long="51.5072" data-lat="0.1275">
  Replace by map 1
</div>

<div class="map" data-long="74.0059" data-lat="40.7127">
  Replace by map 2
</div>
```

I was considering using something like (this should be loaded only if map divs exist):

```
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function()
{
  google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'sensor=false', callback: function()
  {


  }});
});
```

The code I would like to apply to each map is something like [Google Maps Code](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map#the_finished_code):

```
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: `if ( $('.map').length > 0 ) { code here }`

Answer (score 0):

See a solution for loading Google Maps API async:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12602845/1491212

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}
window.loadGoogleMaps = function(){
    if(gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}
```

Then just do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    }
    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);

    if($('.map').length){
        window.loadGoogleMaps();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not using $.getScript and Google Loader? It might be usefull when loading multiple scripts ... No?

Comment: If you can listen to a specific event for each script I don't see a reason why you shouldn't use it. I never tried it. Looks good! The interesting part is the `if($('.map').length)` condition