# getting an error as first child of undefined when using google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

getting an error when using google maps multiple times with the following code

```
var checkForMap = function() {
    $scope.post.showMap = true;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.post.location.x, $scope.post.location.y);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var mapHolder = $('.map_class')[$scope.$index];
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: myLatlng
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent($scope.item.post.post.locationName);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
if ($scope.post.locationName != null) {
    checkForMap();
} else {
    $scope.post.showMap = false;
}
```

using google maps multiple times.By using $scope.$index i can display exact location.

Comment: Getting an error at  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, myOptions);

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas thanks  angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
    at Object._.Yf (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false:80:265)
    at new rg (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false:86:76)

Comment: I've received this error before. The cause in my case was that the google maps script was trying to load before the DOM was fully loaded.. so it tried to append the map to an element that didn't exist yet.

Comment: @BFG thanks how to do that

Comment: @Shiva As I said, that was the problem when I received that error but it might not be for you. Take a look at he answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922764/load-google-maps-v3-dynamically-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps JavaScript API provides a way to register for [event notifications](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events), in particular `onload` event which triggers  once an HTML page is fully loaded.

To ensure map is getting initialized once the page is loaded replace

```
checkForMap();
```

with

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', checkForMap);
```

Comment: Thanks@vadim Gremyachev .It is taking more time(10M) to display map.After the page loading.