# How to dynamically load scripts in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using jQuery mobile running on top of PhoneGap. Facing an issue where i am using Google places API+jquery UI maps. Problem is that i only need to load the google maps API script when loading a particular page. But seems all scripts are loaded at first DOM load in jQuery mobile. Issue is then i have to ask the user to turn on data on the mobile because otherwise a JavaScript error is thrown from the jQuery UI maps script.

Is there any way i can dynamically load the Google Maps API script when loading a particular page in jQuery mobile?

Edit:

I have the jQuery Ui maps related javascript files to load as well, so that is where the complication arises. Appreciate any help..

Edit: Adding code example;

```
<div data-role="page" id="showInfoPage" data-theme="a" data-close-btn="right">



                                <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
                                                <h1>Information</h1>
                                </div>

                                <div data-role="content">

                                                <h1 id="elementName"></h1>

                                                <h2 id="elementAddress"></h2>             
                                                <a id="elementCallHos" data-role="button" class="tele" style="height:40px;"><span id="elementTele"></span></a>
                                                 <a id="elementCallHos1" data-role="button" class="tele" style="height:40px;display:none;"><span id="elementTele1"></span></a>
                                                <a id="elementGoogleMaps" data-role="button" class="googleMapsBtn" data-rel="page">Google Maps</a>

                                </div>



                </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.services.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>



 $( document ).on( "pageshow", "#nearestHotels", function() {

    checkLocation("nearestHotelsList","showInfoPage",['lodging']);                                      
 }
);

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var infowindow;
var lat;
var lng;
var lng;
var service;
var reference;
var initialLocation;


var nearestInfoArr = [];
var ulId = null;
var pgId = null;
function checkLocation(listViewId,pageId,typeToSearch) {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        ulId = '#'+listViewId;
        pgId = '#'+pageId;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;

            callPlaceService(lat, lng,typeToSearch);
        }, gpsFail, {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            maximumAge : 300000
        });
    }
}

function callPlaceService(lat, lng,typeToSearch) {
      $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();  
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom : 15,
        center : pyrmont,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var request = {
        location : pyrmont,
        radius : 5000,
        types: typeToSearch
        //keyword : 'Bank'
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);   


    service.search(request, callback);
}


function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var requestDetails = {reference : results[i].reference};

            service.getDetails(requestDetails, checkDetailedStatus);
        }
    }

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}

function checkDetailedStatus(details, detailStatus) {
    if (detailStatus == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {


        $(ulId).append('<li><a href="'+pgId+'?id='+details.name+'&searchTerm='+details.name+","+details.formatted_address+'&address='+details.formatted_address+'&tele='+details.formatted_phone_number+'">'+details.name+'</a></li>');

        $(ulId).listview("refresh");
        $(ulId).trigger( "updatelayout");       
    }
}

function gpsFail() {
    alert('Failed to retireve location');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you move your code to load the Google Maps API script to a function that you call for that specific page.

So instead of something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

Have something like this:

```
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE");
```

Have a look at the following for additional options:

- [Dynamically Loading Google Maps api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398657/dynamically-loading-google-maps-apis)
- [Load google maps v3 dynamically with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922764/load-google-maps-v3-dynamically-with-ajax)

Comment: I tried this solution. Issue is though i wait until the scrip is loaded to call the maps functions, i still get an undefined exception. What could be the problem? Do i have to embed the script retrieved on to the page itself?

Comment: thing is i have to load not only the google maps api, but also the jquery ui maps javascript files in my project..

Comment: Can you give a large enough sample of code to see what is going on?

Comment: Hi meewOk, addded code example. Appreciate if you can help me out.. i have run out of all my options

Comment: This actually worked. My issue was that i needed the jQuery ui map js files to load afterwards as well. This was achieved using the done() method which waited until the script was loaded. Thank you for your answer. I will mark this as the answer.