# External Library with es6/react comes up as 'not defined'

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6

I keep getting `'google' not defined` even though I've definitely loaded the google library (at least I see that from chrome dev tools).

I am trying to hit the [google places api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) for a very simple front end webpage. In learning front end web dev (incl. react), I've learned how to use npm basically, and importing and all, but using an external library is giving me trouble.

I should be able to load the google places library via this in my index.html

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBq8oeYyntc6d0JP5iaqMtPMTBhxiItdJw&libraries=places"></script>`

but now I'm trying to use [little-loader](https://github.com/walmartlabs/little-loader) in my index.js before the `ReactDOM.render(...)` like this

```
import LittleLoader from 'little-loader';

LittleLoader(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBq8oeYyntc6d0JP5iaqMtPMTBhxiItdJw&libraries=places", 
    function (err) {
        console.log("hi paul!");

        // This is just to check I *have* the google library loaded/working
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
});
```

All the examples online seem to imply that this should work (either with the  tag or at least in the callback of little-loader). But no matter what I do, I get `./src/index.js Line 14:  'google' is not defined  no-undef`. I **do** see the google maps library in chrome dev console->sources, and I get an object if I just type `google` into the console.

So...how can I use the google library in my normal javascript...? My best guess is that I'm somehow deferring/asyncing the loading, but putting a setTimeout on the usage of that `google.maps.LatLng...` doesn't help.

I'm trying to figure out this front end development world. I'm a bit lost in the ES6 js way of thinking. I'm sure this is easy, but I am struggling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google maps API initializes itself asynchronously and it can't be used until two things happen:

1. The code for the google maps API is loaded via your `LittleLoader()` function.
2. Google maps finishes it's own async initialization.

One way to know when both are done is to specify a `callback=xxxx` query parameter in the Google maps API URL.  Then, when it's done loading, it will call that function and you can then use all the facilities of Google maps.  That callback will get called when both of the above items are done.

import LittleLoader from 'little-loader';

```
function initMap() {
    // This is just to check I *have* the google library loaded/working
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
}

LittleLoader(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBq8oeYyntc6d0JP5iaqMtPMTBhxiItdJw&libraries=places&callback=initMap", 
    function (err) {
        console.log("hi paul!");
});
```

You can see this type of example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.

I suspect that the callback function needs to be accessible from the global scope for this to work properly.

Similar example using dynamic script loading here: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7cu2F/

And, same thing here: [Dynamically Loading Google Maps api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398657/dynamically-loading-google-maps-apis)

Comment: Oooh ok. So it does have its own async initialization for itself. You use an unit callback, then any other uses of the library will be in response to the user so the library will have been set up by then. That makes sense. Thanks so much. I'll try this when I get to my computer next.  Question tho, what is the general best practice for using a 3rd party lib? Script tag in index.html and then the lib should "just work" in global scope? What about async libraries like this, is this pattern of creating an init function the best practice?

Comment: @mgs - If a library has its own asynchronous initialization (like Google maps has), then it has to provide either a callback or a promise that indicates when it is ready for use.  Most libraries do not have that type of async initialization though so you don't usually see this.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the help. I'll try it when I get the opportunity and I'll post back if i have any troubles

Comment: I'm back with another question. I have things working, but I want to know why it works like this. 
I have the google library included in the index.html file. In my react component, I still can't access the google object though unless I do `window.google`. Obviously I don't understand how scope works here. I'm wondering what the best practice is here. Is it true that, for everything you include via a script tag (not via package.json + import), you access through the global window.google? Is that the best practice?

Comment: @mgs - I can't tell what you're asking in that comment.  I'd need to see the actual code you're talking about.  For that, I would suggest you ask a new question and show the exact code you want to ask about.

Comment: That's fair. I'm just trying to learn best practices for react/FE. I'll look for what else I can find online and post if I can't find anything. Thanks @jfriend00!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding script to main index.html file. It should be available across the app.

Comment: The whole point of what the OP is trying to do is to dynamically load the google maps API and even if you use a `<script>` tag, the Google maps API still has it's own async initialization that won't be done yet when just the `<script>` tag has been loaded.