# Google Maps callback not always triggering

Tags: javascript, google-maps

**Problem**: It seems like when loading the Google Maps script, the callback is not performed. It might be related to how to load the Google Maps script.

**Context**: My website displays a Map in the frontpage when certain minimum viewport conditions are met. Specifically, I avoid loading it when I'm on mobile. I do not want to use jQuery :)

**Implementation**: The way I'm doing it is by first loading a small handcrafted script (google-map.js), which does a bunch of things and ends with:

```
function dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.defer = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
};

// Load Google Maps when NOT on mobile
if ( ! mobile ) {
    dynamicallyLoadScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=wIzaScChUs5NxF3Z5LZoxkAS4wca9A7Pk53I024&callback=initMap');
}
```

(The JS key is fake).

**Outcome**: This actually works when I load the site for the first time. I see that google-map.js is loaded, the Google Maps script tag is added to the head, and both resources are loaded and working well. But sometimes (!) when I refresh, the map stops loading and upon inspection I see that the script tag was added successfully, and the resource is loaded, but the initMap() callback function hasn't triggered. If I go to the console, it does fire.

Since this happens only sometimes (and *never* upon a fresh load without cache), I think it might have something to do with a race condition or just with how cache works. But I'm not sure how to address it. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398657/dynamically-loading-google-maps-apis
Loaded dynamically, maybe that's a solution

Comment: Maybe the `async` prop? Dunno for sure, try `defer` instead

Comment: I've upvoted your question for its (not common) clarity.

Comment: Update: I tried adding 'defer' but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Also I discovered that I was wrong with my initial appreciation -- the google maps script does download, but the callback function is not issued. Triggering it manually works.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner and I downvoted it because it does **not** include a [mcve].

Comment: @MrUpsidown You're not in the wrong (you're less indulgent than me).

Comment: FYI that I posted 'a solution' to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in a nutshell**: This is not a very elegant solution imho, but I figured that what I needed to create is some retry logic for loading initMap() when it runs before it should. In other words, I'm diagnosing this as a race condition present when cache is available.

**Implementation**: Added a small function to check every 0.1 seconds if the DOM has an element that only exists when the map is fully loaded. When so, the timer stops, but otherwise, it runs the initMap() function.

```
function checkMaps() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style").length == 0) {
        initMap();
    } else {
        clearInterval(checker);
    }
}

checker = setInterval(checkMaps, 100);
```

Comment: Why downvote him without an explanation?